# Apple dev program expiration, can I renew later?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I signed up for an iPhone development program last December hoping to develop an app but got carried away by other projects in my life. Now I get messages from Apple that my developer account is expiring in a week. I will not be able to post anything in the App Store for the next 6 months at least, thus the question -- if I let it expire now, can I renew, say, in summer of the next year? And, will it have any consequences on my apple ID?

PS. I currently do not have any apps in the App Store, nor that I plan on testing my apps on a real device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can renew/reactivate.  Went through a similar experience myself.

Comment: And if you had an app on the App Store? Will the app continue to work? Will Apple continue to distribute it? (I think no) Will you be able to reactivate the account and update the same application? (transparent from the user point-of-view)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. There no consequences. You can let your apple Dev expire since you don't have any apps and not wanting to test you don't need it for now. When you get ready again apply and get another one.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, too. It's nice to know this.